# Disappearing accessoryInputView on menu open

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am using ECSlidingViewController in my project and I also have a messages view, in which I have an `accessoryInputView` to imitate the iOS Messages app. Now when I open my menu on this view, the accessoryInputView slides down and is nowhere to be found. I can no longer find it under the `UITextEffectsWindow` in the debugger's UI Hierarchy view.

Where did it go? Do I need to call it back? If so, how?

Comment: Not a solution, but I disabled the menu gesture (the messages view was a detailpage, so I can still go back to swipe the menu open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the menu gesture on the detailpage (of a navigation controller that was on my menu in my case) fixed the problem.